# Elasticsearch query for OR and AND functions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elasticsearch and am doing a bit of query basics.

I have to retrieve count of those documents that:
Either contain netflow.src_port ['10','11','12'] OR netflow.dst_port ['20','21','22']
AND timestamp being within the last 15 minutes.

I have a basic query as below:

```
    body: {
    "query": {
      "bool":{
        "should": [
          {"terms": { "netflow.src_port": ["10","11","12"] }},
          {"terms": { "netflow.dst_port": ["20","21","22"] }}
        ],
        "must": [
          {"range" : {
            "@timestamp" : {
              "gt" : "now-15m"
            }
          }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Going by the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html), `should` is used to note that: a document need not contain src_port or dst_port in that range, but if it does, then calculate cost accordingly.

What I actually need is an or condition for them.

If my explaination is not clear, the below might convey what I'm trying to achieve:

```
if( (netflow.src_port contains [10 or 11 or 12] || netflow.dst_port contains [20 or 21 or 22]) && timestamp is within the last 15m.
```

What exactly do I need to do to get the desired result?

Comment: This is how you looked for your query in  Kibana's - Dev tools?

Comment: No. I'm using [node's version of elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) to query my docs but I do believe querying via kibana should have similar structure, correct?

Comment: please add the response you got- I'm working with Kiban, and if the syntax is the same -  you have some syntax errors

Comment: I've updated with the kibana specific query. Replaced single quotes with double quotes and removed extra commas

Comment: good, but still I don't see your response

Comment: The response is a few hundred documents. I'm not sure how that might help, although, I can past it in jsbin or somewhere. However, I am questioning the correctness of my query since it still picks up records that don't fall under the range (10, 11, 12 or 20,21,22)

Comment: I think the ```should``` clause must come within the ```must``` clause. Let me  try something.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `should` section of your query to include a `minimum_should_match` attribute. e.g.

```
{
  "bool":{
    "should": [
      {"terms": { "netflow.src_port": ["10","11","12"] }},
      {"terms": { "netflow.dst_port": ["20","21","22"] }}
    ],
    "must": [
      {"range" : {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "gt" : "now-15m"
        }
      }}
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 1
  }
}
```